# Custom TabBarController is not working in iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, ios12

The client might not understand what "More" means in default Tab bar controller in ios. So we used JFATabBarContoller. [JFATabBarController](https://github.com/vermont42/JFATabBarController) is a pluggable replacement for UITabBarController that eliminates this limitation. 
After implementing it the Custom tab bar is working fine in all the simulators, but it is not working properly in the physical devices ios12.

Comment: As this question is specific to a Library, you should create [issue](https://github.com/vermont42/JFATabBarController/issues) for it. That will be more helpful.

Comment: if you get issue with iPhone X and above please check:Yes,this issue is exactly same as yours:-https://github.com/vermont42/JFATabBarController/issues/7